# Add quotation marks & comma to each word in a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a list of words such as:

```
string1
string2
string3
....
string12312
```

How do I convert them these words in delimited manner that output could be used as a JS array, i.e. `"String1", "String2"..., "String12312"` --- in other words how do I add quotation marks and commas? I understand this an be done in shell, but I guess any other solution would be okay as long as the result can be converted into an array.

Comment: This "list of words", where are they? in a file? a variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
sed 's/^\|$/"/g' file | paste -d, -s
```

```
"string1","string2","string3","....","string12312"
```

Comment: Or its POSIX equivalent: `sed 's/.*/"&"/' file | paste -sd , -`

Answer (score 3):

Using Awk:

```
awk '{printf "\"%s\", ", $0}' file
```

Comment: you answered it too! so merry christmas again!

Comment: Has a trailing comma FWIW...

Answer (score 3):

```sh
xargs printf '"%s", ' <file
```

...will work with your example data:

```
"string1", "string2", "string3", "....", "string12312",
```

Comment: Merry Christmas, sed maniac! :)

Comment: @jasonwryan - i rather like that one. it's catchy. and it beats *asshole*. and to you, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't affraid the comma at the end of line you can use

```
printf '"%b", ' $(<file)
```

which outputs

```
"string1", "string2", "string3", "....", "string12312",
```

Comment: (assuming $IFS has its default value and those strings don't contain any of those $IFS characters, and that they don't contain globbing characters. That's one case where you're using the split+glob operator but forgot to tune it to your need).

Answer (score 1):

Could always just turn it into a JSON array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

chomp ( my @data = <DATA> ); 
print to_json ( \@data );

__DATA__
string1
string2
string3
string12312
```

Or as a one liner:

```
perl -MJSON -e 'print to_json ( [map{s/\n//gr}<>] )'
```

Pipe on stdin or specify a filename (like grep/awk etc.)

Both output (the latter when fed your example):

```
["string1","string2","string3","string12312"]
```

Can format it as 'pretty' JSON with `print to_json  ( \@data, {pretty=>1})` which'll add linefeeds and indentation.

(that one liner above is based on a newer perl that you *might* have installed. If that doesn't work: `perl -MJSON -e 'chomp(@a=<>);print to_json ( \@a )'`

Comment: You probably want `chomp(@a = <>)` in the oneliner

Comment: Yes, true. Although I've had a slightly better idea.